# NotJSONError("Notebook does not appear to be JSON: ''..."

Tags: jupyter-lab

I get the above `NotJSONError("Notebook does not appear to be JSON: ''..."` error when I try to open some, but not all, of my .ipynb files in Jupyterlab. I have read that this is due to a config.json file. However, I cannot find such a file in the .jupyter folder. I tried reinstalling a default config file; still cannot open the file. I understand from what I have researched that I need to remove commas from the config file ... but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the Dropbox backups were offline only; will leave this answer in case anyone else has similar issue. So check when opening files that they are on a local drive or available....